# Throw exception, but json response get status SUCCESS

Tags: php, symfony, jsonresponse

I have this part of code in Controller, but when i make this action and IF works fine and the error message appears in console log.

But it looks like 'success' has status true. And it shouldn't

```
Try {
    if ($last['date']) {
        if ($last['date']->format('d-m-Y') == $par['date']) {
                throw new \Exception('error', 500);
            }
    }

    return new JsonResponse([
        'success' => true,
        'data'    => $content,
        'message' => 'success'
    ]);
} catch (\Exception $exception) {

    return new JsonResponse([
        'success' => false,
        'code'    => $exception->getCode(),
        'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
    ]);
}
```

JQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/app/url",
    data: TableData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response.message);
        $('#message').html('<p class="alert alert-success">' + response.message + '</p>');
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response.message);
        $('#message').html('<p class="alert alert-danger">' + response.message + '</p>');
    }
});
```

Comment: To report an error, you would have to return a HTTP response in the 400 or 500 range. In your current implementation you made a request with a successful response. That response contains a piece of Json which happens to have a property `success` with the value `false`, but your Ajax call doesn't know that that indicates an error. You could implement that in JavaScript by parsing the response, but the better and more 'pure' way would be to make PHP return a proper error response code. See [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: But shouldn't CATCH block work when i throw exception?

Comment: Ok, so instead of throwing exception i should resturn response with success: false

Comment: No the other way around. Returning a response with `success: false` is what you currently do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX code is receiving the response as `success` every time, regardless of the JSON content, because you're always sending a `200` response (which is success). To tell AJAX to process the response as an error (and go to the `error` method instead of `success` method in your AJAX response handler), you need to send an error code in the response, i.e. `400`, like this:

```
return new JsonResponse([
        'success' => false,
        'code'    => 400,
        'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
    ], 400);
```

So, if you're throwing your custom `Exception`s, you need to set the `code` property for each according to their real HTTP meaning.

Now, the `success` and `error` handlers in AJAX have different parameters. In `success`, the first parameter is `data`, simply the data returned from the server. On the other hand, in `error`, the first parameter is an `jqXHR` object. To access the data in this object, you have a handful of different parameters, but what you need now, since you have JSON, is `jqXHR.responseJSON`. So, now your error message will be in `response.responseJSON.message`, not in `response.message`. See more about this [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

Comment: Could you tell me how i can get error message, from jsonRespone with your  answer?

the old way gives me UNDEFINED (my love)

Comment: Your data in the `error` method is now in `response.responseJSON`, so get it with `response.responseJSON.message`. To further debug this, put `console.log(response);` in the error handler, so you can see all the response object has.